# Failed to read environment variable

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, arcgis

i'm installing eclipse plugin, ArcGis Runtime SDK for java, but when i create a simple map application and then i run it, it wasn't right

my code :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import com.esri.runtime.ArcGISRuntime;
import com.esri.map.JMap;
import com.esri.map.MapOptions;
import com.esri.map.MapOptions.MapType;

public class coba2class {

  private JFrame window;
  private JMap map;

  public coba2class() {
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setSize(800, 600);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center on screen
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

// dispose map just before application window is closed.
window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
    super.windowClosing(windowEvent);
    map.dispose();
  }
});

// Before this application is deployed you must register the application on 
// http://developers.arcgis.com and set the Client ID in the application as shown 
// below. This will license your application to use Basic level functionality.
// 
// If you need to license your application for Standard level functionality, please 
// refer to the documentation on http://developers.arcgis.com
//
//ArcGISRuntime.setClientID("your Client ID");

// Using MapOptions allows for a common online basemap to be chosen
MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions(MapType.TOPO);
map = new JMap(mapOptions);

// If you don't use MapOptions, use the empty JMap constructor and add a tiled layer
//map = new JMap();
//ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer tiledLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
//  "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
//map.getLayers().add(tiledLayer);

// Add the JMap to the JFrame's content pane
window.getContentPane().add(map);
```

}

```
  /**
   * Starting point of this application.
   * @param args
   */

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      coba2class application = new coba2class();
      application.window.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
```

}
}

and after i run this, i got this warning.

> Java version : 1.8.0_25 (Oracle Corporation) amd64 Rendering engine :
>   DirectX java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find runtime
>   installation. Searched following places: F:\coba2 Failed to read
>   environment variable ARCGISRUNTIMESDKJAVA_10_2_4
>   com.esri.runtime.ArcGISRuntime.getInstallDirectory(Unknown Source)
>   com.esri.runtime.ArcGISRuntime.a(Unknown Source)
>   com.esri.runtime.ArcGISRuntime.getClientLibPath(Unknown Source)

Comment: Tell us more about your "imple map application". What libraries does it use?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your app can't find an ArcGIS Runtime deployment.

If you're running on a machine WITH the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java installed, set the value of environment variable `ARCGISRUNTIMESDKJAVA_10_2_4` to the directory where arcgisruntime10.2.4 is located. The default value is `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS SDKs\java10.2.4`, though the SDK installer should have set this environment variable for you.

If you're running on a machine WITHOUT the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java installed, [create a Runtime deployment](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/guide/build-a-runtime-deployment.htm) and place it in the working directory for your app (`F:\coba2` in your case). This is how you deploy ArcGIS Runtime to end-user machines.

Alternatively, you can set the directory containing the ArcGIS Runtime deployment programmatically using [`ArcGISRuntime.setInstallDirectory(String)`](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/api-reference/com/esri/runtime/ArcGISRuntime.html#setInstallDirectory(java.lang.String)), but I don't recommend it because then your app will require that the Runtime deployment be located in the same directory on every machine.